# Advanced Yet Simple ToC with Multilevel List Issue

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I'm trying to develop a Table of Contents in Word capable of being updated, linked, etc. to the parts of the document.  I'm looking to modify the static template my University supplied that is void of any field codes (i.e., this ToC would need to be manually updated).

I've spent the last 4-5 hours learning about TC field codes, advanced ToC creation, etc., but I'm having a hard time building this exact example.

[image: ToC Example]

In my document I also use Headings 1-4 as a multilevel list with Chapter 1 being Heading 1, Sub-Heading 2 is ex:1.1, Sub-heading 3 is ex: 1.1.1, ... etc. Is this the wrong way to go about this and still model a ToC from the image above?  I'm hoping to format my thesis like this following example:

[image: First Page Example]

Comment: As you are using styles for your headings/subheadings, you don't need TC fields; just create a table of contents that picks up the Heading 1 to 4 styles that you have used.  In Word 2010, just go to the References tab and insert a Table of Contents (first button at left).  To add Heading 4 style to your TOC, click the Options button on the dialog that appears, scroll down the list of styles and set Heading 4 to a TOC level value of 4.  Alternatively insert a TOC field manually and add the switch \t "Heading1,1,Heading2,2,Heading3,3,Heading4,4".

Comment: You only need TC fields for your Chapter headings, so the word Chapter (which should be part of the outline numbering) doesn't appear in the TOC.  When inserting your TOC, select Options button on the dialog and delete the value for Heading 1 so you don't pick up the style and the TC field for Chapter headings and get duplicate entries.  Then add \f to your TOC field code to include the TC fields (in addition to the \o "2-4" or \t "Heading 2,2,Heading 3,3,Heading 4,4" already there).  In TC fields use 2 cross-references for number (with \t) and paragraph text, which will update if edits made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer seems to involve a lot of extra work.  As per my earlier comment above, you can avoid all this by just using a TC field with STYLEREF fields to create the Chapter entries in the TOC.  Because the TC field will use STYLEREF fields, you can simply copy and paste that for each chapter.  The TOC field just needs editing to remove Heading 1 and add \f to pick up the TC fields, and then adjust TOC1 and TOC2 style paragraph settings to get the alignment you want.

In the first screenshot below you can see the placement of the TC fields.

The second screenshot shows the outline numbering set up which includes "Chapter" and is linked to Heading 1, 2 and 3 styles (you can add other levels of numbering if required).

The third screenshot shows the field codes (rather than field results) for the TC and TOC fields.

Note inside the TC field are two STYLEREF fields, looking for Heading 1 style.  The first has the switches \n \t added so that it shows the number but without the word "Chapter" (eg 1).  Press the TAB key after the field and then insert the second STYLEREF field which has no extra switches as we just want the text using Heading 1 style (eg Introduction).  The \l 1 tells it to make this the top level (TOC1) in the table of contents.

In the TOC field, you'll see that it has \f (this tells Word to include the TC fields in the table of contents) and \t "Heading 2,2,Heading 3,3" which tells Word to also include text with those styles applied (ie your subheadings and sub-subheadings).  Again, if there are more levels of numbering you want to include, just add those styles to the list - Heading 2,2 means add Heading 2 as level 2 (TOC2) in the table of contents.  Note we have not included Heading 1,1 in the list of styles as we will already get those headings with our TC fields.

[image: Sample page showing fields and TOC]

[image: Styles set up to include Chapter in outline numbering]

[image: TC field code and TOC field, showing codes]

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here is that you want the chapter headings in the chapters themselves to consist of "Chapter *x*" followed by a line/paragraph break and then the chapter title; but the TOC has to have just the chapter number followed by a tab space and then the chapter title. But at the same time, the chapter titles have to have autonumbering applied (via the multilevel list), so that the chapter numbers are included in the numbering for subheadings. It can all be done, but it takes some work. Unfortunately, I could manage to get all the indents and alignment in the TOC to work only by inserting two separate TOCs (one for the "List of Figures" and "List of Tables" headings, and one for everything else). Here's what I did:

Set up a multilevel list. (It sounds as though you've already done this.) Level 1 of the list is assigned to **Heading 1** style, uses an arabic numeral that's preceded by the word "Chapter" and a space. Set **Follow number with** to **Nothing**. Level 2 is assigned to **Heading 2** style, and uses an arabic numeral preceded by the number from Level 1 and then a period. And Level 3 is assigned to **Heading 3** style, and also uses an arabic numeral, preceded by the number from Level 1, a period, the number from Level 2, and a period.

Insert the cursor between the autogenerated "Chapter"+chapter number, and insert a line break (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

For each chapter, follow these steps:

1. Select the text for the chapter title, and insert a bookmark around it (named, e.g., **ch01** for the first chapter, **ch02** for the second, and so on).
2. Position the cursor at the end of the paragraph for the chapter title, and insert a `TC` field that includes two embedded `REF` fields:

   > `{ TC "{ REF ch01 \n \t }   { REF ch01 }" }`

   The first `REF` field retrieves the autogenerated number of the paragraph that the referenced bookmark appears in but removes the word "Chapter", and the second retrieves the text inside the bookmark (i.e., the chapter title). Between the closing brace for the first `REF` field and the opening brace for the second, press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, so that the number and title will be separated by a tab space in the TOC.
3. On the TOC page, type "Table of Contents" in one paragraph, "Page" in a second, and "Chapter" in a third. Apply **TOC Heading** style to the first, and right-align the second.
4. Place the cursor at the beginning of the "Chapter" paragraph, and insert a custom TOC from **References** > **Table of Contents**. Click **Options**, and clear all the values in the **Available styles** list. In the box for the style that you used for the "List of Figures" and "List of Tables" headings (presumably **Table of Figures**), enter a value (I used **4**, for reasons having to do with formatting, because it looks as though your TOC only has 3 levels total). Click **OK** to insert the TOC.
5. Place the cursor at the end of the "Chapter" paragraph, and insert another custom TOC. Click **Options**, clear the **1** out of the field for **Heading 1** style (but leave a **2** for **Heading 2** and a **3** for **Heading 3**), and then select the **Table entry fields** check box at the bottom of the dialog box. Click **OK** to insert the TOC.

In the first TOC, the headings for the List of Figures and List of Tables will be pulled in based on styles. In the second TOC, the chapter info (chapter number + tab space + chapter title) will be pulled in from the `TC` fields that you added. The various subheadings will be pulled in based on styles, using the autonumbering from the multilevel list that you set up.

Here's my example:

[image: TOC]

Answer (score 0):

These are excellent descriptions (new user, not enough rep yet to post the images directly). The multi-level list setup you screenshotted is exactly what I was already using.

Here is my syntax example which works excellent: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grhYq.png)

The only issue I'm having now is attempting to insert a tab between "1" and "Introduction" within the TOC, and correcting the tab after the subheading number, between "1.1" and "Background and Signifance" to 0.25.  [TOC Tab Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6r40.png). I've achieved my desire spacing and so forth in TOC 1 and TOC 2 style paragraph format but am having difficulty figuring out the these tab insertions.